# How to display a set number of jsx elements depending on number placed in an input field. React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input field that takes in a number.(between 1 and 30) I want to display an array of items depending on what number is placed in that text field. how can this been done with React hooks. I have something basic for a start like this, but this might not even be the best way to start this.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ value: "" });
  const [myArray, updateMyArray] = React.useState([]);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    updateMyArray((arr) => [...arr, `${state.value}`]);
  };
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let { value, min, max } = event.target;
    value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));
    setState({ value });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={state.value}
        min={""}
        max={100}
      />
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Confirm</button>
      {state.value && (
        <>
          <div>
            {myArray?.map((e) => (
              <div>{e}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: So if a user enters 20 in the input field, you want it to show 20 items?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
updateMyArray(new Array(state.value).fill(""));
```

This will create a new array with the length of `state.value` and asign it to `myArray`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be helpful for you.

```
function App() {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
  const [submittedAmount, setSubmittedAmount] = useState(0);

  // optionally
  const onSubmit = () => {
    setSubmittedAmount(amount);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let { value, min, max } = event.target;

    value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));
    setAmount(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={amount}
        min={0}
        max={100}/>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Confirm</button>
      
      { /* you can use amount instead of submitted amount if you want */
      {submittedAmount > 0 && Array.from({ length: submittedAmount }, (_, index) => <div key={index}>{index}</div> )}
    </>
  );
}
```

In my opinion if you can skip submitting and use only **amount** state. Thanks to this your UI will change automatically after input value change without submitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of value, you can loop till that number, before the render, like:

```
  const items = [];
  for (let i; i < state.value; i++) {
        items.push(<div>{i}</div>);
  }

  return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div> 
  )
```